# How do I convert a jupyter notebook project into a standalone web application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, prediction

I am new to machine learning & python. I found a predictive machine learning program on jupyter notebook. Is it possible to convert that jupyter project into a standalone web application? Do I need any libraries for it ? I want to demonstrate the chart & prediction formally. Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Traditional question here: "What have you tried?". Actually what prevents you from treating jupyter as a a "standalone web application"? Run jupyter-notebook and dispay what's needed. Or you need something else?

Comment: Are you planning to deploy it somewhere? Make it accessible to the public? Search for Python web application frameworks, then copy the Jupyter notebook codes into a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it is possible. If you want to convert it to web application, you should use **Flask**, **Django**, etc.  **Flask** is easy and light one, try it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use django or pyramid or flask and use the same codes in a reorganized way.